# AWS MWAA - Airflow - Load Connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

Im considering move Airflow from ECS to MWAA that apparently works well. But from CICD point of view there are some limitations to load connections.
Based in documentation we cannot setup connections using command line based in what they say here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/access-airflow-ui.html#call-mwaa-apis-cli

I know we can do it using UI, but is not the intention. Does anyone knows how to deal with that or if there is any way to do it on automated way?

Many Thanks
Xavy

Comment: You should be able to use the `aws_mwaa/cli` endpoint and pass `connections add`

I haven't done it with connections but that's how I provision `variables`

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/airflow-cli-command-reference.html#airflow-cli-commands-supported

Comment: What did u end up doing?

Answer (score 1):

There are Couple of options here depending on the version of MWAA you are using.

- You can keep your connection information in AWS secrets manager and then get the CLI token and run airflow commands using that refer -> https://dnx.solutions/how-to-use-apache-airflow-cli-with-amazon-mwaa/
- Other approach is you can integrate AWS Secrets manager directly using Airflow config and secrets backend. Please check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/manage-connections.html

Hope this helps. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a step in the DAG that will programmatically add the connection if it's not already present in the environment:

```
def add_connection_callable(**kwargs):
    connection: Connection = Connection(
        conn_id="foo",
        conn_type="HTTP",
        host=kwargs['host'],
        port=kwargs['port']
    )
    session: Session = settings.Session
    db_connection: Connection = session.query(Connection) \
        .filter(Connection.conn_id == "foo") \
        .first()
    if db_connection is None:
        logging.info("Adding connection \"foo\"..")
        session.add(connection)
        session.commit()
    else:
        logging.info("Connection \"foo\" already exists.")

add_connection: PythonOperator = PythonOperator(
    task_id="add_connection",
    python_callable=add_connection_callable,
    op_kwargs={
        "host": "{{ dag_run.conf['Host'] }}",
        "port": "{{ dag_run.conf['Port'] }}"
    },
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: This needs triggering the DAG to load connections. Wouldn’t auto load on every CICD